# MSAL .AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword throws MSAL.Xamarin.iOS.4.27.0.0.MsalClientException: ErrorCode: parsing_wstrust_response_failed

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, identity, azure-ad-msal

await PCA.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(scopes, userName, securePassword)

Using this line throws the following exception error.

This is for an xamarin.ios project.

I used working code that logged into ADB2C. Then I replaced .WithB2CAuthority with .WithAuthority and updated the tenant id, client id, uris and scopes.

I also updated the info.plist.

Error:

```
[0:] MSAL.Xamarin.iOS.4.27.0.0.MsalClientException: 
    ErrorCode: parsing_wstrust_response_failed
Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalClientException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at Microsoft.Identity.Client.WsTrust.CommonNonInteractiveHandler.GetWsTrustResponseAsync (Microsoft.Identity.Client.WsTrust.UserAuthType userAuthType, System.String cloudAudienceUrn, Microsoft.Identity.Client.WsTrust.WsTrustEndpoint endpoint, System.String username, System.Security.SecureString securePassword) [0x000e4] in <6fbdadf1482a430d8bbf62059cfed90f>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Microsoft.Identity.Client.WsTrust.CommonNonInteractiveHandler.GetWsTrustResponseAsync (Microsoft.Identity.Client.WsTrust.UserAuthType userAuthType, System.String cloudAudienceUrn, Microsoft.Identity.Client.WsTrust.WsTrustEndpoint endpoint, System.String username, System.Security.SecureString securePassword) [0x00119] in <6fbdadf1482a430d8bbf62059cfed90f>:0 
  at Microsoft.Identity.Client.WsTrust.CommonNonInteractiveHandler.PerformWsTrustMexExchangeAsync (System.String federationMetadataUrl, System.String cloudAudienceUrn, Microsoft.Identity.Client.WsTrust.UserAuthType userAuthType, System.String username, System.Security.SecureString password) [0x00186] in <6fbdadf1482a430d8bbf62059cfed90f>:0
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this error by updating the keychain groups to include the bundle name.